# Abstract Algebra - Size of the generating set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Given a group $G$, say of some size $k$. Can it be shown that it actually has a generating set H whose size can be expressed in terms of $k$? Intuitively, one can say it should be say around $O(\log k)$, as we indeed multiply an element so many times and it begins to repeat after sometime, similar to a Divide and Conquer strategy, where we throw away half the problem at every instance and then move on.

Comment: Yes your argument is essentially correct.

Comment: Here's more information (with an answer from Derek Holt): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225172/how-large-can-the-smallest-generating-set-of-a-group-g-of-order-n-be

Answer (score 1):

$O(\log k)$ may be an upper bound on the number of generators. But $Z_n$ has only a single generator for any value of $n$, and $D_n$ is generated by just two generators.

Comment: But the answer to the question is yes, any group of order $k$ can be generated by $O(\log k)$ elements.